# bundler: command not found: spring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring

I'm running through the process of creating a new rails app, but I've run into some issues with gems.

[I ran `rails new test_app`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txg2J.png), and it began  'create...' statements, but it had issues finding certain gems and commands.

[I tried doing some installations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7T7F.png) that I found on various solution forums, but it seems like "spring" wasn't what was missing on those, and what solved the problems in those cases aren't fixing what's happening on mine.

The error that comes up is `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`, as seen in the pictures. As I understand it I have to install this gem, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it, since the commands I've found online are giving that error.

Comment: You do not seem to be in your app directory. after creating your  `rails  new app` cd into your app directory `cd appname` then run `bundle install`.

Comment: @Hizqeel I did such and got a lot of errors saying "Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.", and it ended with the error "An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling."

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: It looks like a bundle error. Please update your question with the full error message and run`gem install bundler` after that succeed run `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` hope this will work. If that work let me know and update your question with will error message.

Answer (score 3):

From the pictures that you post I see that your not in your new rails app directory.

after you run `rails new test_app`
you should change the working directory to test_app

```
cd test_app
```

your running bundle install in your root directory so that is giving this error

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `gem install bundler`. It will install bundler if not already there. 
After that you can do `bundle install`